# Looking to add a filter to a Visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce

Usual disclaimer: I'm not a developer but can understand and manipulate existing code if it isn't too complex!

I found some code that creates a page that allows editing of multiple records, in this case Opportunities.  Works great but I'd like to expand on it with the following functionality:

1. Either pass in a predefined filter set or allow user to set filter
   criteria
2. Resulting list can be grouped (i.e. by Opportunity Owner, Region, etc.)
3. Would allow for multiple pages (i.e. displays 25 out of 100)
4. Ability to display dynamic Totals either at the sub group level or Grand Totals
5. Once user hits Save they are returned back to the page so that they can review and make further changes.

I know that with each requirement I'm looking at it adds a level of complexity but I'm hoping to be able to slowly build this solution so I'll be patient.

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thanks
Mike

**What I have so far is this:**

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" 
   recordSetVar="opportunities" 
   tabStyle="Opportunity" sidebar="false"> 

  <apex:form > 
 <apex:pageBlock > 
  <apex:pageMessages /> 
   <apex:pageBlockButtons > 
     <apex:commandButton value="Save" 
                     action="{!save}"/> 
  </apex:pageBlockButtons> 
  <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!opportunities}" 
             var="opp"> 
 <apex:column value="{!opp.name}"/> 
 <apex:column headerValue="Forecast Category"> 
      <apex:inputField value="{!opp.My_Forecast_Category__c}"/> 
    </apex:column> 
    <apex:column headerValue="Close Date"> 
      <apex:inputField value="{!opp.closeDate}"/> 
    </apex:column> 
    <apex:column value="{!opp.Amount}"/>
      <apex:column headerValue="Override"> 
      <apex:inputField value="{!opp.Amount2__c}"/> 
    </apex:column>
  </apex:pageBlockTable>      
</apex:pageBlock> 
 </apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```